# get certain record while sum of previous records greater than a pecentage in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table: FooData

```
ID   Count
1    54
2    42
3    33
4    25
5    16
6    9
8    5
9    3
10   2
```

I want to fetch the record that sum of Count column is greater than a certain percentage like 90.

For this example, the sum of all the records is 189, and 90% of it is 170.1, we can see the sum from ID 1 to 6 is 179, and it is greater than 170.1 so the record ID 6 should be returned.

btw, temporary table is not allowed because I need to do it in a function.

Comment: An iterator is required.  One, set a sum of all the records to a variable from an initial query. Then query the table via a cursor.  Each iteration check if the running sum  (current record plus any previous records is greater than the passed percentage.  If so, stop and return that record ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
  t2.id,
  SUM(t1.value) AS runningTotal
FROM FooData t1 
INNER JOIN FooData t2 
  ON t1.id <= t2.id 
GROUP BY t2.id
HAVING SUM(t1.value) * 100. / 
  (SELECT SUM(value) FROM @FooData) > 90
ORDER BY SUM(t1.value)
```

But also be aware of the potential performance issue with [triangular joins in running totals](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/).

Answer (score 3):

Another version of a triangular join.

```
declare @T table(ID int primary key, [Count] int)
insert into @T values (1, 54), (2, 42), (3, 33),(4, 25), (5, 16), (6, 9), (8, 5), (9, 3),(10, 2)

;with R(ID, [Count], Running) as
(
  select T1.ID, 
         T1.[Count],
         cast(T3.[Count] as float)
  from @T as T1
    cross apply (select sum(T2.[Count])
                 from @T as T2
                 where T1.ID >= T2.ID) as T3([Count])
),
T(Total) as
(
  select sum([Count])
  from @T
)
select top 1 R.ID, R.[Count], R.Running
from R
  inner join T
    on R.Running / T.Total > 0.9
order by R.ID
```

Comment: thank you very much for your input, but I preferred the answer from 8kb.